# Visual Studio 2015 with ASP.NET core : only manual CLI works to build

Tags: asp.net, build, visual-studio-2015, release

One of my coworker and I are having a weird problem with Visual Studio 2015 (all the latest updates as of today) and asp.net core (.net 4.6).

When we want to build/debug, we have to manually go to the Package Manager Console and type 'dotnet build' in the folder of the target project. The Build/Rebuild from the top menu isn't working at all. No release build neither.

When web select Build from the menu, the Build is successfully completed without errors, even if I deliberately create some.

Kind of annoying because all worked normally with asp.net 5.

I also have to manually copy/paste the wwwroot from the source folder to the debug folder to get the latest changes from my project. (not normal at all)

Side note : our web projects are running perfectly in debug

Side note : installed latest [Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/32f1fa1b-cdd5-4bd3-8f51-cd8f099f46bc)

Tested : Already Reinstalled Visual Studio, without any luck

Tested : win7 and win10.

Tested : VS2015 community and enterprise

dotnet --version is 1.0.0-preview2-003121

Thanks SO!

Comment: This looks like the mirror opposite of my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408415/asp-net-core-1-0-web-config-is-being-overwritten-causing-cgi-exceptions . I would imagine same issue, opposite symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/windows-prerequisites#issues : DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1